# Как проверить, является ли число палиндромом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо написать функцию с одним параметром, которая проверяла бы, является ли введенное число палиндромом. если является, программа должна вернуть True, а если нет - False (не строкой, а типом boolean)

Comment: дубликатов — вагон: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+палиндром

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin тем не менее, именно этого вопроса нет, а специфика задачи требует задать именно этот вопрос

Comment: «именно этот вопрос» является составным и его следует декомпозировать в два: 1. как преобразовать число в строку. 2. как определить, что строка является палиндромом.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin моя цель-понять, является ли число палиндромом. Мне не известно, как это сделать, поэтому я не стал задавать вопрос по преобразование в строку

Comment: палиндромом/непалиндромом может являться только текстовое представления числа в заранее оговоренной системе счисления. да, конечно, вы этого можете не знать. ну что же, повышайте уровень своих знаний. удачи! дальнейшую дискуссию поддерживать не собираюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(n):
    n = str(n) 
    return n == n[::-1]
```

превращаем число в строку, потом мы её сравниваем с развёрнутой версией себя, если они равны то возвращается `True` иначе `False`

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что нужно использовать if? Все что после операции сравнения напоминает функцию slice, но не совсем понятно, как это работает. Поясните?

Answer (score 0):

способ 1:

преобразовать число в строку и перевернуть

```
is_poly = str(value) == str(value)[::-1]
```

способ 2:

без преобразования в строку разобрать число на цифры

```
arr = []

while value != 0:
    arr.append(value % 10)
    value //= 10

is_poly = arr == arr[::-1]
```